# sump pump discharge pipe connection broken inside basement

Tags: sump-pump

[image: ELBOW PIPE CONNECTOR IS CRACKED][image: SUMP PUMP DISCHARGE PIPE]I just bought a house and now discovered the sump pump extended discharge pipe is broken at the elbow going out the basement wall about 5 feet from floor.  Can you help with suggestion to repair?
I saw a sump pump discharge hose on a YouTube video; do you think I could change out/replace the 5' pvc pipe for a sump pump discharge hose?

Comment: Some photos of the problem maybe ... ?

Comment: Thank you I didn't think to take a pic but will take some & post

Comment: Make sure that you hit the 'edit' link just below your question when you have some pics to add. Don't post them down in the 'answers' section or try here in the comments.

Comment: Hi all - I just uploaded a couple photos of my sump pump discharge pipe that somehow got broken at the elbow connecting to discharge exit

Comment: Is that a concrete wall which the pipe runs into at the top, or would you be able to open it up a little to get access to a little more of the pipework behind the wall?

Comment: And fyi the reason it broke is that it's completely unsupported over that 5ft length. The plastic bend at the top is not intended to support the weight of 5ft of full pipe in addition to whatever vibration occurs when the pump runs.

Comment: Hi yes it is a concrete block wall that the top goes into the wall and apparently drains into an underground outlet pipe (frozen ground).  Any ideas on a diy solution?

Answer (score -1):

Cut the pipe in half and put a cuppling on it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We prefer answers with enough detail so that the original poster can understand what to do. Would you  add some more info to your answer?

Comment: I saw a sump pump discharge hose on a YouTube video; do you think I could change out/replace the 5' pvc pipe for a sump pump discharge hose?